# Select values from table A based on values from table B?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a very basic post and reply system to get a better understanding of MySQL and PHP. I have two tables: posts and comments.

```
posts(post_id, post_user, timestamp, post_text)
comments(comment_id, post_id, timestamp, comment_text)
```

What I want to do is order the posts by the ones that have the most recent reply. So I would need to `SELECT * from posts ordered by comments.timestamp desc` since I want to order by most recent comments and not by the original post's timestamp. I can't figure out a proper query that works.

Comment: only by timestamp you can do this, why you dont want to use timestamp?

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide sample data and your expected output

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this

```
SELECT  p.* 
FROM  posts p 
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.post_id= p.post_id
ORDER BY c.timestamp desc
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes, but this is close but not right on. It shows the same original post multiple times and doesn't show every post in the post table. It does update to the post with the most recent comment is on top though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id, post_user, timestamp, post_text, 
       most_recent_comment
  FROM posts NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT post_id, 
                MAX( timestamp ) AS most_recent_comment
          FROM comments 
         GROUP
            BY post_id ) AS t
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_user, timestamp, post_text,
       NULL AS most_recent_comment
  FROM posts
 WHERE post_id NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM comments );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  A.Post_Id FROM
(SELECT P.Post_Id,C.TimeStamp,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY S.Post_Id ORDER BY C.TimeStamp DESC) Rnk  FROM POSTS p INNER JOIN  COMMENTS C
ON P.Post_Id=C.Post_Id) A
WHERE A.Rnk=1
ORDER BY A.TimeStamp DESC
This is SQL SERVER version.
So hope you can find Mysql version for it
```

Comment: "to get a better understanding of MySQL..."